# How many cores does the Asus 7" MeMO Pad have?

Tags: tablet

How many cores does the Asus 7" MeMO Pad have? Is it only single core?
The [specifications](http://www.asus.com/Tablets_Mobile/ASUS_MeMO_Pad/#specifications) only state that the CPU is VIA WM8950.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tablet with the CPU you mentioned ([Asus Memo Pad ME172V](http://www.gsmarena.com/asus_memo_pad_me172v-5249.php)) is a single-core device. More info on the CPU can be found [here](http://www.cnx-software.com/2012/01/06/wondermedia-prizm-wm8950-cortex-a9-soc/).

> WonderMedia Technologies, a subsidiary of Via Technologies, has unveiled the Prizm WM8950, a single core Cortex A9 processor running up to 800 Mhz with a Mali-400 GPU.

Comment: This seems to be the CPU although the tablet specs state 1GHz.